# AndroidManifest.xml file throwing collection of error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, android-manifest

`AndroidManifest.xml` file throwing collection of below errors in `my flutter project`

```
Unresolved package 'flutter'
Unresolved package 'app'
Unresolved class 'FlutterApplication'
Attribute android:usesCleartextTraffic is not allowed here
Attribute android:icon is not allowed here
Unresolved class 'MainActivity'
Attribute android:launchMode is not allowed here
Attribute android:theme is not allowed here
Attribute android:configChanges is not allowed here
Attribute android:hardwareAccelerated is not allowed here
Attribute android:windowSoftInputMode is not allowed here
Attribute android:autoVerify is not allowed here
Attribute android:scheme is not allowed here
Attribute android:host is not allowed here
Attribute android:scheme is not allowed here
Attribute android:scheme is not allowed here
Attribute android:host is not allowed here
Unresolved package 'facebook'
Unresolved class 'FacebookActivity'
Attribute android:configChanges is not allowed here
Unresolved package 'facebook'
Unresolved class 'CustomTabActivity'
Attribute android:scheme is not allowed here
```

[image]